# Como fazer <li><div class="class" onclick="window.location='link';"></div> abrir em nova aba?

Tags: html

Eu estou a tentar abrir um link numa `div` numa nova aba, mas 
     `target="_blank"` não está a funcionar.

```
 Eu queria abrir o link numa nova aba.

<li>
    <div class="clientes" target="_blank" onclick="window.location='LINK';">
        TEXTO
    </div>
</li>
```

Alguém me poderia ajudar?

Comment: O atributo `target` é para âncoras... Porque não usas `<div><a target="_blank" href="o-teu-link.com">texto</a></div>` que é a semântica correta?

Comment: Sou só um miudo a tentar fazer umas coisitas :P Obrigado, vou já ver

Comment: Sergio, ao mudar a cor do <a mudo todos os <a da pagina, por isso que nao usei.

Comment: Muda a côr para ficar claro ao leitor que é um link... mas podes mudar a cor para o que queres. Mas faz o que querias que é abrir noutra aba?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar uma tag  para fazer o link de urls. Para abrir em nova aba:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Mas, se por algum motivo, precisa mesmo que seja dessa forma, pode utilizar:

```
<li>
    <div class="clientes" onclick=" window.open('http://google.com','_blank')">
        TEXTO
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar :)

Comment: Apenas lembre-se que utilizar `_blank` em páginas externas é perigoso, a página alvo terá como manipular a página de origem (via `window.opener`), [veja isto para mais informações](https://cybersins.com/target-blank-vulnerability-phishing/) ou [isto](https://medium.com/@jitbit/target-blank-the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever-96e328301f4c). Se utilizar o `_blank` utilize o `noreferrer` e `noopener` com conjunto.

Comment: Obrigado Aline, era mesmo isto :)

Answer (score 3):

O atributo `target` é para [âncoras](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) e não funciona em elementos `div`.

Deves usar `<div><a target="_blank" href="o-teu-link.com">texto</a></div>` que é a semântica correta. Se queres mudar a côr podes usar CSS.

Exemplo:

```css
.clientes a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="clientes"><a target="_blank" href="o-teu-link.com">texto A</a></div>
<div class="clientes"><a target="_blank" href="o-teu-link.com">texto B</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Com o codigo que está na pergunta é necessário o javascript abrir a pagina portanto o codigo fica.:

```
<li>
   <div class="clientes"  onclick="window.open('LINK');">text</div>
</li>
```

Com as questões acho que o que se pretende é tag a que ficará assim.:

```
<li>
   <a target="_blank"  href="LINK">text</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar :)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos(as) que responderam.
Desculpem se fui um bocado chato, visto que só sei o basico do básico.
Obrigado mesmo!